# How foldLeft works with Seq of tupels?

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala, so struggling to understand Syntax. Please check below code.

```
def myDef(entityMap: Seq[(DataName.Value, DataFrame)]) : Seq[Map[Int,Info]] = {

    val depenInfo = Seq[Map[Int,Info]]()

    entityMap.foldLeft(depenInfo)((info,entity) => {
    val(dataName: DataName.Value, df: DataFrame) = entity
    info ++ df.createDepenInfo(dataName)    
 })
}
```

what am I getting is, `Seq` of tuples having to two types `(DataName.Value, DataFrame)` and return type of `myDef` is `Seq` of `Map`.

After that, create one empty `Seq` of `Map`, then feed this empty Map to `entityMap.foldLeft` so that it could add more values in it.

Remaining part I kind of literally stuck to understand. Can anyone please help me to understand what's happening ? If possible with any very simple example similar to above with output.

Thanks

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/Seq.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) should be your best friend. It says exactly what `foldLeft` does. Don't be afraid to search! [Here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html#example) is a nice example of how to use it (read only the `foldLeft` part).

Answer (score 0):

Since there are many user defined class I don't know, I try to mock your data type as following:

```scala
import scala.collection.{immutable, Seq}

object Example {

  object DataName {
    type Value = Int
  }

  case class DataFrame(fakeData: String) {
    def createDepenInfo(value: DataName.Value): Seq[Map[Int, Info]] = Seq(Map(value -> fakeData))
  }

  type Info = String

  def myDef(entityMap: Seq[(DataName.Value, DataFrame)]): Seq[Map[Int, Info]] = {

    val depenInfo = Seq[Map[Int, Info]]()

    entityMap.foldLeft(depenInfo)((info: Seq[Map[Int, Info]], entity: (DataName.Value, DataFrame)) => {
      // here is Pattern matching on tuples,
      // here we extract (dataName: DataName.Value, df: DataFrame) from tuple entity: (DataName.Value, DataFrame)
      // see: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html
      val (dataName: DataName.Value, df: DataFrame) = entity

      // ++ is a method of Seq, it contact two Seq to one
      // e.g. Seq(1,2,3) ++ Seq(4,5,6) = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6)
      info ++ df.createDepenInfo(dataName)

    })
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val data: immutable.Seq[(DataName.Value, DataFrame)] = (1 to 5).map(i => (i, DataFrame((i + 'a').toChar.toString)))

    // Vector((1,DataFrame(b)), (2,DataFrame(c)), (3,DataFrame(d)), (4,DataFrame(e)), (5,DataFrame(f)))
    println(data)

    val res = myDef(data)

    // List(Map(1 -> b), Map(2 -> c), Map(3 -> d), Map(4 -> e), Map(5 -> f))
    println(res)
  }

}
```

raw data: `Vector((1,DataFrame(b)), (2,DataFrame(c)), (3,DataFrame(d)), (4,DataFrame(e)), (5,DataFrame(f)))`

let's say `info ++ df.createDepenInfo(dataName)` is `result`

1. info = `Seq()`, entity = `(1,DataFrame(b))`, reuslt=`Seq(Map(1 -> b))`
2. info = `Seq(Map(1 -> b))`, entity = `(2,DataFrame(c))`, result=`Seq(Map(1 -> b), Map(2 -> c))`
3. info = `Seq(Map(1 -> b), Map(2 -> c))`, entity = `(3,DataFrame(d))`, result=`Seq(Map(1 -> b), Map(2 -> c), Map(3 -> d))`

and so on...

You see, during each caluclation, the value `info` is "saved"(with a init value from `deepInfo`), and the `entity` value is "read" from `entityMap`.

So the final result is `List(Map(1 -> b), Map(2 -> c), Map(3 -> d), Map(4 -> e), Map(5 -> f))`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `info` is the accumulator, `depenInfo` is the initial value, and `entity` is a map item (i.e. a key-value tuple). Here's a simpler example where `acc` is the accumulator and `kv` is the key-value pair being "read" from the map.

```
Map(1->2).foldLeft(0)((acc, kv) => {
  val (k, v) = kv;
  println(s"$k, $v, $acc");
  acc + k + v
})
// prints: 1, 2, 0
// result: 3
```

To read about the accumulator pattern: https://www.arothuis.nl/posts/accumulators-and-folds/

As for the `++`, that is the operator/method in `Seq` (sequence) which concatenates this sequence to another sequence. Simple example with concatenating length 1 sequences together:

```
Seq(1) ++ Seq(2)
// Seq(1, 2)
```